# How can i find the checkbox if i only know the Some text in code using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<tr id="Any_22" class="value-table list-row-even">
   <td class="selection-column">
      <input id="Checkbox_1_1" type="checkbox" onclick="doCheck( this, 'value-table-selected', 'value-table' )" name="Checkbox_1_1">
   </td>
   <td id="columnValues_19" class="first-selection" onmouseover="sCC(this)">
       <span>
          <table id="container_7" class="vo-label" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="skinImage">
                   <img border="0" src="/images/icons/small/pawn_glass_white.gif">
                </td>
                <td id="Any_23" class="remainder"> I_am_here </td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
       </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I click the check box if I know only "I_am_Here" txt.
I have tried  `//td[normalize-space(text())='192.168.9.2']`. But it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath that works for the HTML snippet posted :

```
//tr[td[normalize-space()='I_am_here']]/td/input[@type='checkbox']
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e70ace1299a95ff28fd747baef57cab1)</kbd>**

**brief explanation :**

- `//tr[td[normalize-space()='I_am_here']]` : find `tr` where `td` child element has inner text equals `"I_am_here"`
- `/td` : from such `tr`, find child element `td`
- `/input[@type='checkbox']` : from such `td`, return `input` element where `type` attribute value equals `"checkbox"`

**output :**

```
<input id="Checkbox_1_1" name="Checkbox_1_1" onclick="doCheck( this, 'value-table-selected', 'value-table' )" type="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide any code, the answer will be also conceptual.

So, you should get the nodes tree by known text (`I_am_Here`) and then find nearest node with name `input` and type `checkbox`.

The nodes tree can be obtained by traveling through `parents` and `siblings` of found node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//td[contains(text(),"I_am_here")]/ancestor::body/input[@type="checkbox"]
```